# Replacing text with new text when button click

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax

I have 3 data in the JSON file and want each data to be displayed 1 by 1 at a single click.The problem is the previous data was'nt replaced by the new data as the button was click. They ended up being side by side (image below). How do i overcome this? Thanks in advance.

[image]

**JSON FILE**

```
[
  {"quote": "Everyday Is A New Day"},
  {"quote": "Trust Your Guts"},
  {"quote": "All The Best"}
]
```

**HTML**

```
<p id="text"></p>
<button id="btn">GENERATE</button>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var text = document.getElementById("text");
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
var i=0;

btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  ourRequest.open('GET', 'data2.json');
  ourRequest.onload = renderHTML;
  ourRequest.send();
});

function renderHTML(data) {
  var htmlString =data[i].quote;
  i++;
  text.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', htmlString);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
text.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', htmlString);
```

just use

```
text.innerHTML = htmlString;
```

insertAdjacentHTML doesn't replace the html.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `insertAdjacentHTML`, set `innerHTML` directly. So your new function would look like:

```
function renderHTML(data) {
var htmlString =data[i].quote;
i++;
i %= data.length;            // new
text.innerHTML = htmlString; // changed
}
```

I also inserted the line `i %= data.length;` so you don't go off the end of the array, and instead loop around to the beginning of `data`.

Comment: @DanialWafiy no problem! when you get answers to a question, you may want to accept an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers